# Razor - Umbraco: For each loop

Tags: razor, umbraco

```
@{var feed = Model != null ? Model : null;}

<dl id="accordion">
    @foreach (var item in feed.DescendantsOrSelf("SubSubPage")){

    <dt>@item.Name</dt>
        <dd>@item.description</dd>
}

</dl>
```

I am trying to show a list of accordions on a page that im doing in umbraco

The setup is something like

main page

```
sub page
    sub sub page 
    sub sub page 

sub page
    sub sub page 
    sub sub page
```

But with the code above its just listing them out in one big accordion

what im trying to do is list them out in a seperate accordion for each 'sub page' if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working I needed to do this:

```
@foreach(var item in feed.DescendantsOrSelf("SubPage")){
<dl id="accordion">

 <dt>@item.Name</dt>

 @foreach(var itemSub in item.DescendantsOrSelf("SubSubPage")){

 <dt>@itemSub.Name</dt>

 }

 </dl>
}
```